# List nuget packages on GitHub Packages

Tags: nuget, github-package-registry

I have nuget packages hosted on [GitHub Packages](https://github.com/mabead?tab=packages). Then, when I try to list the packages in the github nuget feed using `nuget.exe`, it tells me that it can't list the packages in the feed:

```
> nuget list -Source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mabead/index.json"
WARNING: This version of nuget.exe does not support listing packages from package source 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mabead/index.json'.
No packages found.
```

Note that the packages are properly listed in Visual Studio when I use the window that opens up after clicking on "Manage Nuget Packages for Solution". So the feed works but it does not work with the nuget cli.

I am using version 5.5.1 of nuget.exe.

Any idea what I am using to be able to list the packages using the CLI?

Answer (score 9):

This beahvior is caused by the fact that not all nuget server expose the same set of API. The full set of possibly implemented APIs is defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/overview#resources-and-schema).

Let's compare the service index of nuget.org with the one of GitHub. The one of nuget.org is available [here](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json) and it contains a very extensive set of APIs.

```
{
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "@id": "https://azuresearch-usnc.nuget.org/query",
      "@type": "SearchQueryService",
      "comment": "Query endpoint of NuGet Search service (primary)"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://azuresearch-ussc.nuget.org/query",
      "@type": "SearchQueryService",
      "comment": "Query endpoint of NuGet Search service (secondary)"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://azuresearch-usnc.nuget.org/autocomplete",
      "@type": "SearchAutocompleteService",
      "comment": "Autocomplete endpoint of NuGet Search service (primary)"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://azuresearch-ussc.nuget.org/autocomplete",
      "@type": "SearchAutocompleteService",
      "comment": "Autocomplete endpoint of NuGet Search service (secondary)"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://azuresearch-usnc.nuget.org/",
      "@type": "SearchGalleryQueryService/3.0.0-rc",
      "comment": "Azure Website based Search Service used by Gallery (primary)"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://azuresearch-ussc.nuget.org/",
      "@type": "SearchGalleryQueryService/3.0.0-rc",
      "comment": "Azure Website based Search Service used by Gallery (secondary)"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-semver1/",
      "@type": "RegistrationsBaseUrl",
      "comment": "Base URL of Azure storage where NuGet package registration info is stored"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/",
      "@type": "PackageBaseAddress/3.0.0",
      "comment": "Base URL of where NuGet packages are stored, in the format https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/{id-lower}/{version-lower}/{id-lower}.{version-lower}.nupkg"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2",
      "@type": "LegacyGallery"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2",
      "@type": "LegacyGallery/2.0.0"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package",
      "@type": "PackagePublish/2.0.0"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/symbolpackage",
      "@type": "SymbolPackagePublish/4.9.0",
      "comment": "The gallery symbol publish endpoint."
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://azuresearch-usnc.nuget.org/query",
      "@type": "SearchQueryService/3.0.0-rc",
      "comment": "Query endpoint of NuGet Search service (primary) used by RC clients"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://azuresearch-ussc.nuget.org/query",
      "@type": "SearchQueryService/3.0.0-rc",
      "comment": "Query endpoint of NuGet Search service (secondary) used by RC clients"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://azuresearch-usnc.nuget.org/autocomplete",
      "@type": "SearchAutocompleteService/3.0.0-rc",
      "comment": "Autocomplete endpoint of NuGet Search service (primary) used by RC clients"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://azuresearch-ussc.nuget.org/autocomplete",
      "@type": "SearchAutocompleteService/3.0.0-rc",
      "comment": "Autocomplete endpoint of NuGet Search service (secondary) used by RC clients"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-semver1/",
      "@type": "RegistrationsBaseUrl/3.0.0-rc",
      "comment": "Base URL of Azure storage where NuGet package registration info is stored used by RC clients. This base URL does not include SemVer 2.0.0 packages."
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://www.nuget.org/packages/{id}/{version}/ReportAbuse",
      "@type": "ReportAbuseUriTemplate/3.0.0-rc",
      "comment": "URI template used by NuGet Client to construct Report Abuse URL for packages used by RC clients"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-semver1/{id-lower}/index.json",
      "@type": "PackageDisplayMetadataUriTemplate/3.0.0-rc",
      "comment": "URI template used by NuGet Client to construct display metadata for Packages using ID"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-semver1/{id-lower}/{version-lower}.json",
      "@type": "PackageVersionDisplayMetadataUriTemplate/3.0.0-rc",
      "comment": "URI template used by NuGet Client to construct display metadata for Packages using ID, Version"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://azuresearch-usnc.nuget.org/query",
      "@type": "SearchQueryService/3.0.0-beta",
      "comment": "Query endpoint of NuGet Search service (primary) used by beta clients"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://azuresearch-ussc.nuget.org/query",
      "@type": "SearchQueryService/3.0.0-beta",
      "comment": "Query endpoint of NuGet Search service (secondary) used by beta clients"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://azuresearch-usnc.nuget.org/autocomplete",
      "@type": "SearchAutocompleteService/3.0.0-beta",
      "comment": "Autocomplete endpoint of NuGet Search service (primary) used by beta clients"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://azuresearch-ussc.nuget.org/autocomplete",
      "@type": "SearchAutocompleteService/3.0.0-beta",
      "comment": "Autocomplete endpoint of NuGet Search service (secondary) used by beta clients"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-semver1/",
      "@type": "RegistrationsBaseUrl/3.0.0-beta",
      "comment": "Base URL of Azure storage where NuGet package registration info is stored used by Beta clients. This base URL does not include SemVer 2.0.0 packages."
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://www.nuget.org/packages/{id}/{version}/ReportAbuse",
      "@type": "ReportAbuseUriTemplate/3.0.0-beta",
      "comment": "URI template used by NuGet Client to construct Report Abuse URL for packages"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://www.nuget.org/packages/{id}/{version}?_src=template",
      "@type": "PackageDetailsUriTemplate/5.1.0",
      "comment": "URI template used by NuGet Client to construct details URL for packages"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver1/",
      "@type": "RegistrationsBaseUrl/3.4.0",
      "comment": "Base URL of Azure storage where NuGet package registration info is stored in GZIP format. This base URL does not include SemVer 2.0.0 packages."
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/",
      "@type": "RegistrationsBaseUrl/3.6.0",
      "comment": "Base URL of Azure storage where NuGet package registration info is stored in GZIP format. This base URL includes SemVer 2.0.0 packages."
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/",
      "@type": "RegistrationsBaseUrl/Versioned",
      "clientVersion": "4.3.0-alpha",
      "comment": "Base URL of Azure storage where NuGet package registration info is stored in GZIP format. This base URL includes SemVer 2.0.0 packages."
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://api.nuget.org/v3-index/repository-signatures/4.7.0/index.json",
      "@type": "RepositorySignatures/4.7.0",
      "comment": "The endpoint for discovering information about this package source's repository signatures."
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://api.nuget.org/v3-index/repository-signatures/5.0.0/index.json",
      "@type": "RepositorySignatures/5.0.0",
      "comment": "The endpoint for discovering information about this package source's repository signatures."
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://api.nuget.org/v3/catalog0/index.json",
      "@type": "Catalog/3.0.0",
      "comment": "Index of the NuGet package catalog."
    }
  ],
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "http://schema.nuget.org/services#",
    "comment": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment"
  }
}
```

The one of GitHub available [here](https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mabead/index.json) contains a much more limited set of supported APIs:

```
 {
      "version": "3.0.0-beta.1",
      "resources": [
        {
          "@id": "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mabead/download",
          "@type": "PackageBaseAddress/3.0.0",
          "comment": "Get package content (.nupkg)."
        },
        {
          "@id": "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mabead/query",
          "@type": "SearchQueryService",
          "comment": "Filter and search for packages by keyword."
        },
        {
          "@id": "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mabead/query",
          "@type": "SearchQueryService/3.0.0-beta",
          "comment": "Filter and search for packages by keyword."
        },
        {
          "@id": "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mabead/query",
          "@type": "SearchQueryService/3.0.0-rc",
          "comment": "Filter and search for packages by keyword."
        },
        {
          "@id": "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mabead",
          "@type": "PackagePublish/2.0.0",
          "comment": "Push and delete (or unlist) packages."
        },
        {
          "@id": "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mabead",
          "@type": "RegistrationsBaseUrl",
          "comment": "Get package metadata."
        },
        {
          "@id": "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mabead",
          "@type": "RegistrationsBaseUrl/3.0.0-beta",
          "comment": "Get package metadata."
        },
        {
          "@id": "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mabead",
          "@type": "RegistrationsBaseUrl/3.0.0-rc",
          "comment": "Get package metadata."
        }
      ]
    }
```

So, the API required to execute `nuget.exe list` is supported by nuget.org but not by GitHub, thus explaining the warning explained in the console.

Comment: I take it this is why `Visual Studio 2019`'s Package Manager tool doesn't work with a GPR source? 

Comment: It looks like the nuget.exe client's `list` functionality still uses the older NuGet v2 search API only.
When using a v3 source, that requires the `LegacyGallery` resource to be listed in its index.json, pointing to the prefix for the V2 API endpoints, like `Search()`.

Comment: Has anyone found a mitigation?

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, if you know a partial name, at the very least you can find out the *latest version* of a package, or set of packages.

I know that's not a solution: it is not the same as getting a list of all available packages. But it gives you important info: whether or not a new package is available that's higher than your current one.

The command:

```
nuget search "XYZ" -Source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/Company-Name/index.json" -PreRelease
```

Replace `XYZ` with a substring of a known package. Replace `Company-Name` with your company name, or whatever the location of your packages `index.json` is.

The option `-PreRelease` at the end does what you'd expect: it includes pre-releases.