# GitLab.com Nuget Package registry - This version of nuget.exe does not support

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I've tried to use the nuget package registry provided by gitlab.com but there seems to be some kind of API error with the newest version of nuget and the nuget tool from the dotnet CLI. Authentication seems to work but for example `nuget list -Source gitlab` where gitlab is the name of the added nuget source I get `This version of nuget.exe does not support listing packages from package source`.
I've found this issue here, where it seems something in that direction could be the problem but otherwise I have no idea how to fix this.
[List nuget packages on GitHub Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176823/list-nuget-packages-on-github-packages)

Is this a bug of gitlab side or some misconfiguration on my side?

Comment: Which versions of gitlab and nuget you are using?